# 'ambiguous indirect export' error JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, module

I am getting this error:
`Syntax Error: ambiguous indirect export`
in Firefox. Sadly there is nothing to find on Google...

- This is my import:

```
<script type="module">
    import {someFunctionINeed} from "./js/functions.js";
    ...
</script>
```

- This is my export:

```
export function someFunctionINeed(cname) { ... }
```

- compilerOptions from my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "watch": true,
    "removeComments": true
}
```

- and something that's maybe relevant from the `package.json`:

```
"type": "module"
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

Ok, I found the solution: It's important to set these properties in the `tsconfig.json`:

```
"module": "ESNext",
"target": "esnext",
```

Otherwise it doesn't "compile" the way I need it to support importing/exporting of functions.

Comment: This did not work!

Answer (score 2):

(**EDIT:** removed introductory paragraph for clarity)

In my case I was trying to include {x, y, z} from .jsx within a .js file, that was what the error said was ambigious. I changed module.exports ={} to export default {}, but the error stayed. Turns out that in that .js file I require("./yet/another/jsx/file"),but require is not defined. That error was printed after I **removed the default keyword** so to sum up:

- Importing from a .jsx file that have a single "export default"
- exporting ~without default~ objects in a js file
  and
- importing from that .js file within a jsx file

solved it for me. Try to remove the default statements and stick with import (at least in the frontend, I am building a preact app with vite) seems to save some debugging time. I hope so. Good luck, fellow coders, may the Web-Assembler come so that javascript can die in peace. <3

Addition from ChatGPT:

"Import" and "require" are used for module loading in JavaScript. "Import" is used in ES6+ for frontend and backend, while "require" is used in CommonJS for backend. To avoid ambiguous errors, use consistent import/export syntax, avoid circular dependencies, and always specify file extensions.

Comment: Most of the first paragraph is completely irrelevant. Your opinions and comments like "it seems to be a hot topic" have nothing to do with the answer.

Comment: I agree, so I removed it. However, readers should acknowledge that this is not a comprehensive answer but my personal approach due to my experience respecting the temporal context, and that there will be changes in the behavior over time

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, fixed it by including `"type": "module"` in package.json file.

(I know it's not an answer to your question but somebody may find it useful since there's not much info at Google about that error)

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same exact same error but with a different cause.
For me, the problem was the `name` in `package.json` was the same as the filename I was importing.

**Solution:** Changing the filename and import path

Observed with Vite 4.9.3, TypeScript 4.9.3, and Firefox 109.

Comment: Funny enough, that used to fix it for me as well one or another time. I even learnt something new, that a file extension like .cjs can fix code. Who would have guessed :)

Comment: I can confirm. After renaming the export enum to be different with a file name, it starts work. Before I got "ambiguous indirect export: [Here is enum name]" in firefox and  "No matching export for import" in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you mistype the identifier you're importing, for example:

```js
// In the export file:

export function someFunctionINeed(cname) { ... }
```

```js
// In the import file:

// This identifier is the wrong case, the "S" should be lowercase
import { SomeFunctionINeed } from "./js/functions.js";
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I added a new dependency without restarting Vite's dev server. I guess it messed up Vite's caching and silently broke the bundler.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same issue, apparently I forgot to add a comma at the end of the export

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).